# php get facebook like for specific url

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like

I am trying to get the like count for specific urls and I've tried several methods and searched but haven't been able to come up with a solution...here is what I've tried:

Method 1:

```
$fburl = 'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.olympusmons.com%2Fradio%2F%3Fid%3D1377';
$json_string = file_get_contents('http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=' . $url);
$json = json_decode($json_string, true);
```

Method 2:

```
$fql  = "SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, ";
$fql .= "total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM ";
$fql .= "link_stat WHERE url = '".$url."'";

$apifql="https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=".urlencode($fql);
$fb_json=file_get_contents($apifql);
return json_decode($fb_json);
```

Method 3:

```
$json_string = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' . $url);
$json = json_decode($json_string, true);
```

Now this last method if I go to that url (http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.olympusmons.com/radio/?id=1377) it returns always 4 but true value should be 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value 4 its for the number of share of this url, There are no likes or comment so both equal 0.

Take a look to this one with comments...
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.example.com/

Comment: I just did a test with this url: https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.olympusmons.com/radio/?id=1355 and shows shares 4, yet I just clicked on like so it should show 1..yet it doesnt

Comment: I check it in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/, No one like that URL, So you will get the same results from the Graph API... Maybe it will take time...

Comment: ok i tested now from there and hit the like, so it changed the "share: 4" to "share: 1", so if thats the case how am I supposed to know when its right or wrong?

Comment: For some reason, Most URL show Shares = (Likes + Shares)... So that all what you can get, Anyway there are so official documentation for that...